# python urllib corrupts downloaded documents

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, download, urllib

For some reason urllib is corrupting documents that i download from a website. The url is definitely correct. The documents download with their correct names but they appear corrupted once opened. There is no encoding on the files so i don't need to decode it. I would really appreciate some help in this problem. 
Here is a snippet:

```
def download_file(url, name):

f = urllib.urlopen(url)
fh = open(name, 'wb')
fh.write(f.read())
fh.close()
print "  File Downloaded : " , name

except Exception:
    raise
```

Comment: They are probably *compressed*. `urllib` does not handle gzip or zlib content encoding.

Comment: there is no compression i did a simple check using the zlib library              " print "** DEBUG : type of encoding: ", f.info().get('content-encoding')"

Comment: this returned "none" so there is no encoding to worry about. any other ideas?

Comment: Use `urllib.urlretrieve` instead. Why recreate this functionality in a method?

Comment: @RitchieRamnial: without more info about the URL you are retrieving or what kind of corruption you see I cannot help you further, really. You could try the `requests` library here perhaps, but the `urllib` handles responses I don't see how it could possibly corrupt anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598769/using-urllib-urlretrieve-to-download-files-over-http-not-working

Comment: Just because it doesn't mention encoding doesn't mean it's not gzip (or deflate) encoded. Some servers are not configured correctly, browsers usually take this into account.

Comment: ahh, ive just done a check and this came up true!                                       if f.info().get('content-encoding') ==  'deflate':
  print("content is DEFLATE!")

Comment: do you know how i would decompress this?